# How to refresh markers position on google maps without clearing and blinking the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to create Google Maps V2 markers which can be updated without blinking/clearing the whole map?
Currently i have to clear the map and then add markers:

```
googleMap.clear();
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()).title(entry.getKey()));
```

But then the map blinks when cleared...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`addMarker` returns `Marker` object.

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()).title(entry.getKey()));
```

Use this object to change its position:

```
marker.setPosition(new LatLng(5, 5));
```