# Blinking marker in Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location, maps

I have some problem on "taxi app" marker disappear for second and appear again 
on locationchanged function 
how to fix this ?

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onDriversLocationResult(GetDriversLocationResultEvent event) {
    if (event.response != ServerResponse.OK)
        return;
    for (Marker marker : driverMarkers) {
        marker.remove();
        driverMarkers.remove(marker);
    }
    for (Driver driver : event.drivers)
        addDriverToMap(driver);
}

public void addDriverToMap(Driver driver) {
    driverMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(driver.getLat(), driver.getLng()))
            .rotation(driver.getBearing())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_taxi))));
}
```

Comment: Please share our code...
Else check are you refreshing map

Comment: Hello ABDALRAHMAN MOLOOD. It would be good if you provided some more specific information about the problem. For example... is there any code?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: please take a look to my code above

Comment: This related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379672/how-to-refresh-markers-position-on-google-maps-without-clearing-and-blinking-the